# Facebook cover photo is not available

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was successfully getting the cover photo up until a week or so ago, but all of a sudden it stopped working. I am using this API call:

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552?fields=cover  (Facebook Developers account)

which still actually works, but my personal account does not return the cover photo:

https://graph.facebook.com/shwnb?fields=cover

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about access token.
I've used `shwnb?fields=cover`

```
    {
  "cover": {
    "id": "409216505785036", 
    "source": "http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/558495_409216505785036_1964211932_n.jpg", 
    "offset_y": 49
  }, 
  "id": "100000900706582"
}
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), an access token should not be required for this.

Comment: Excluding the access token worked up until a week or so ago, then all of a sudden the banner image disappeared from our app.  Adding in the access_token field and switching to https:// fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the access_token, which is required for cover pic and album cover pic.

Check in your browser by getting an access token here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

(note: this token in temporary)

Answer (score 1):

There is an active [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/277195785720028) for this. You should file a repro of this.

I can get a page cover photo without an access token, but a user cover photo requires a token right now.